# Зачем нужны промисы?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise, ecmascript

Я просто никак не могу понять их смысла.

Зачем мне писать промисы (promise) или создавать функции через async/await если я могу просто поставить setTimeout()?

Comment: Очень странно сформулирован вопрос, это как "зачем мне голова, если шляпу я не ношу".

Comment: и каким это образом таймаут заменит промис ?

Comment: Да в том-то и дело, что я не понимаю, зачем он... Все статьи пишут, что это какое-то ожидание.. Так а зачем оно? Как работает и что делает.. Я не могу понять никак. Допустим вот есть у меня функция, которая что-то асинхронно делает, а потом возвращает. Так зачем мне промис, если я прямо в коде функции могу написать, что делать с этим возвращаемым значением. Или, например, просто заключить две функции в одну асинхронную, где они будут последовательно выполняться

Comment: ну асинхронность нужна для того чтобы избежать "залипания" страницы, во время выполнения чего-то

Comment: Да, я ещё пару раз перечитал и, кажись, теперь всё понял)

Comment: избавление от callback hell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Промисы помогают удобно управляться с асинхронными запросами. По сути это похоже на try/catch/finally. В промисах колбэки, переданные в `then` и `catch` выполняются по завершению асинхронного метода в случае успешно или неудачного завершения соотвественно.

Предположим, что `foo` возращает промис, тогда мы можем писать:

```
foo()
  .then((response) => {
    // обработка удачного выполнения кода
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // обработка ошибки
  })
```

Answer (score 11):

**Промисы это удобная замена callback'ам**

Представим что у нас есть функция:

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    // ... делаю дела
    // ... делаю дела
}
```

им мы хотим выполнить другую функцию сразу после того как первая будет завершена:

```
const awesomeFunction = callback => {
    // ... делаю дела
    // ... делаю дела
    callback()
}

const printFunction = () => {
    // ... что то вывожу в консоль
}

awesomeFunction(printFunction)
```

Мы можем переписать ее с использованием промисов, но пока большой разницы это не даст, так как наш код синхронный:

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
        // ... делаю дела
        // ... делаю дела
        resolve()
    })
}

const printFunction = () => {
    // ... что то вывожу в консоль
}

awesomeFunction().then(printFunction)
```

Пока ничего особенного, однако обратите внимание насколько понятнее он стал при [использовании промисов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Ispolzovanie_promisov) и метода [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

На примере единственного callback'а это может быть не так и заметно, но при варианте когда их множество это спасет нас от так называемого [Callback Hell'a](http://callbackhell.ru).

Если Вы еще не сталкивались с таким термином, то представьте как выглядел бы код с сотней callback'ов, вложенных один в другой.

На данный момент:

***Достаточно понимать что промисы это те же самые callback'и, только с более удобным синтаксисом, которые упрощают написание кода и его поддержку.***

Рассмотрим те же варианты при асинхронном коде:

```
const awesomeFunction = callback => {
    // функция printFunction будет 
    // запущена через одну секунду
    setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

const printFunction = () => {
    // ... что то вывожу в консоль
}

awesomeFunction(printFunction)
```

Есть ли разница с синхронным вариантом?

Для нас ее нет, мы все так же вызываем наш callback именно тогда когда мы посчитали это нужным, в данном конкретном случае спустя одну секунду после начала выполнения функции `awesomeFunction`.

Перепишем на промисы:

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}

const printFunction = () => {
    // ... что то вывожу в консоль
}

awesomeFunction().then(printFunction)
```

Предположим что `printFunction` тоже асинхронная, тогда мы сможем [заchein'ить](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-chaining) их одну за другой, поскольку теперь она тоже возвращает нам промис:

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}

const printFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("printed")
        resolve()
    }, 1000))
}

const anotherFunction = () => {
    // ... делаю что нибудь третие
}

awesomeFunction()
   .then(printFunction)
   .then(anotherFunction)
```

Обратите внимание насколько понятнее такая запись типа then then по сравнению с вложенностью callback'ов.

Если мы хотим передать что то из одной функции в другую, то мы можем сделать это так:

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("текст для \"print\"")
    }, 1000))
}

const printFunction = text => {
    console.log(text)
}

awesomeFunction().then(text => printFunction(text))
```

---

В версии [ECMAScript 2017](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html) появился еще более удобный синтаксис для работы с асинхронностью под названием [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Он основан на промисах и по сути не чем от них не отличаться, однако позволяет нам писать асинхронный код почти так же как и синхронный.

Для того что бы указать что конкретная функция является асинхронной нам достаточно добавить специальное слово [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), а перед асинхронной операцией слово [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const awesomeFunction = () => {
    return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("текст для \"print\"")
    }, 1000))
}

const printFunction = text => {
    console.log(text)
}

// что бы не отходить далеко от предидущих примеров
// я завернул вызовы в IIFE
// что это такое см. ниже

(async() => {
    const text = await awesomeFunction()
    printFunction(text)
})()

// если бы мы делали вызовы из другой функции
// то это выглядело бы так

const parentFunction = async() => {
    const text = await awesomeFunction()
    printFunction(text)
}
    
parentFunction()
```

[Что такое IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE)